# pause sound in flash using as2

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2, timeline

i'll using this as2 in the pause button

```
on (press) {
    if (pause!=true) {
        playing=false;
        paused=true;
        stopped=false
        myConditionText="Paused";
        myMusicPosition=_root.my_sound.position/10000;
        _root.my_sound.stop("sound1");
    }
}
```

but whn i play the sound it only 1 time

i want to loop this sound how can i loop this sound...

please help me.

on pause button as is:

```
on (press) {
    if (playing!=true) {
        playing=true;
        paused=false;
        stopped=false
        myConditionText="Playing";
        _root.my_sound.start(myMusicPosition,0);
    }
    _root.my_sound.onSoundComplete = function() {
        _root.myCondition.textColor = 0x00FF00;
        myConditionText="Completed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code will greatly increase your chances to get an answer.  Use the {} button or indent 4 spaces.  I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a number of loops when calling [`sound.start()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000164.html). Or listen for the `onSoundComplete` (like you already do) and just start the sound over.